# How can I disable logging for a certain library?

Tags: java

I use a library in my code to do certain things but it also does a log.warn that is irrelevant to us. It confuses clients. Is there any way to disable logging from a certain library?

Comment: _depends_ on the used logger

Comment: Yea ... it is possible.  Typically you fiddle with the logging configs, either in the config file or programatically.  Details depend on the context.